# MIPS Pipelining Question

Tags: mips, forwarding, pipelining

[image]

Is the forwarding (highlighted by the blue arrow) necessary? I figured the add instruction would successfully write back to register before the OR instruction reads it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`add` is writing to register in the same step that `or` is reading from register, so there's no guarantee that the correct value will be safely in the register at the point `or` sees it--`add` is allowed one full clock cycle to make that write and have the signals propagate throughout the hardware. By contrast, `xor` is safe because it reads from r1 in the *next* clock cycle after `add`'s write.